# Creating prayer bead animation

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to do animation like in the video in jquery but I am stuck with it. My code displays circles but there is no animation in jquery
I don't know why:
[image]

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let XPosition = 0;
    let YPosition = 0;
    const $cercle = $(".cercle");
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        XPosition = e.pageX;
        YPosition = e.pageY;
        $cercle.stop().animate({ top: YPosition, left: XPosition });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .cercle {
                height: 25px;
                width: 25px;
                background-color: #bbb;
                border-radius: 50%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center">
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        <div class="cercle"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the animation I want to do:
[image]

Comment: What do you want help with, you’ve said you don’t know what to do but you haven’t told us anything about what you’re *trying* to do.

Comment: i am trying to do the animation in gif file,my code displays circles but the animation in jquery is not working

Comment: The gif appears to show a bead moving as the cursor is dragged rather than on a click - could you explain in words a bit more what you want the bead to do in relation to the mouse/cursor?

Comment: ok,when the user drags the mouse to the right ,the circle moves to the right following mouse move and a the counter increases by one and the same in the left move but the counter decreases by one as shown in the gif

Comment: There are several issues here. First, your DIVs have a static position. Animation using the top and left properties only works for elements with "position: relative" or "position: absolute". You must add this to the CSS of your DIVs. Second, you don't have a variable that stores which of the beads is actually moving. So with the code you currently have, all the beads will move together. This is probably not what you want. Create a counter that is increased or decreased depending on the mouse position and move only the corresponding bead.

Comment: i know what i should do but i don't know how to do it